# winform C# using sql server 2008

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

I have a problem with database I am using winform in c# when i enter data through form it create a space in name column before data so i want to remove it can anyone help me 
name column has datatype varchar    whereas  contact no has numeric datatype it won't create space before it

My Code:

```
private void btnAddNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string Gender = "";

        if (radioButton1.Checked)
        {
            Gender = "Male";
        }
        else if (radioButton2.Checked)
        {
            Gender = "Female";
        }

        if (txtName.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter the customer name.", "Dairy Management System", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
            txtName.Focus();
        }
        else if (Gender == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter the gender.", "Dairy Management System", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
            grpGender.Focus();
        }
        else if (txtAddress.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter the Address.", "Dairy Management System", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
            txtAddress.Focus();
        }
        else if (txtContact.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter Contact No.", "Dairy Management System", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
            txtContact.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=RANJEETMAURYA;Initial Catalog=Project;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO CustomerDetails
                     (Date, Contact_No, Name, Gender, Address, Email_ID)
VALUES(' " + this.dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + " ',' " + txtName.Text + " ',' " + Gender + " ',' " + txtAddress.Text + " ',' " + txtContact.Text + " ',' " + txtEmail.Text + " ')", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Customer Information Added Successfully.", "Dairy Management System", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            SQLFunctions.Refresh(this.dataGridView1);
            clear();
        }
}
```

Comment: can you show the code and what you've tried? Has the input in the form got the space or do you believe it is being added as you say?

Comment: Might help if you can show an example.  Its not clear what you mean.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :** You are adding extra spaces while providing parameter values in `INSERT INTO` statement as below:

```
        |
        |
       >
VALUES(' " + this.dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + " ',' " + txtName.Text    
+ " ',' " + Gender + " ',' " + txtAddress.Text + " ',' " + txtContact.Text + " ',' " +     
txtEmail.Text + " ')", con);
```

**Suggestion:** your query is open to sqlinjection attacks so i would suggest you to use Parameterised queries to avoid them.

Try This: using `Parameterised Queries`

Replace This:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO CustomerDetails
(Date, Contact_No, Name, Gender, Address, Email_ID)
VALUES(' " + this.dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + " ',' " + txtName.Text + " ',' " + Gender + " ',' " + txtAddress.Text + " ',' " + txtContact.Text + " ',' " + txtEmail.Text + " ')", con);
```

With This:

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO CustomerDetails
    (Date, Contact_No, Name, Gender, Address, Email_ID)
    VALUES(@Date,@Contact,,@Name,@Gender,@Address,@Email)", con);

 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date",this.dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact",txtContact.Text);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name",txtName.Text);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender",Gender);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the spaces

```
" ',' " + txtName.Text.Trim() + " ',' " + Gender + " ',' "
```

to

```
"','" + txtName.Text.Trim() + "','" + Gender + "','"
```

but You better delete all these string concatenation and start using SQL parameters

Answer (score 0):

look at this line

```
VALUES(' " + this.dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + " ',' " + txtName.Text + " ',' " + Gender + " ',' " + txtAddress.Text + " ',' " + txtContact.Text + " ',' " + txtEmail.Text + " ')", con);
```

you have placed a space before and after the single quotation. for example

```
' " + this.dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + " ',
```

Actually you have specified space after and before all the value assignment.

BTW, this is not a good method to Insert/Update/Delete operation in database. You should use Parenthesized Query instead.

```
SqlCommand Cmd = Connection.CreateCommand();
Cmd.CommandText = "Insert Into [TableName](Column1,Column2,Column3)Values(@Column1,Column2,Column3)";
Cmd.Parameters.Add("@@Column1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
Cmd.Parameters.Add("@@Column1", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = "Shell";
Cmd.Parameters.Add("@@Column1", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value = System.DateTime.Now;
Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some additional spaces right after and before "'". Remove them, because it will directly inserts into database.

Use this :

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO CustomerDetails
                     (Date, Contact_No, Name, Gender, Address, Email_ID)
VALUES('" + this.dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "','" + txtName.Text + "','" + Gender + "','" + txtAddress.Text + "','" + txtContact.Text + "','" + txtEmail.Text + "')", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Customer Information Added Successfully.", "Dairy Management System", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            SQLFunctions.Refresh(this.dataGridView1);
            clear();
```